# How can I make my web page look good in browser windows of different sizes?

Tags: html, css

I've got a question about optimizing webpages... hmm, let me start over from the beginning.

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="header"> Text... </div>
    <div id="body"> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
#header
    {
        background-color: green;
        width: 50%;
        height: 25%;
        left: 25%;
        position: absolute;
    }

#body 
    {
        background-color: red;
        width: 50%;
        height: 55%;
        left: 25%;
        top: 25%;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

The problem is that whenever I minimize the window a bit, my divs shrinks together. That's not how I want it to appear. After figuring out a while how to solve this problem I came up with this "great" idea to make a div wrap that cover all the other divs.

So then my divs need a wrap right?

```
<div id="wrap"> 
    <div id="header"> </div>
    <div id="body"> </div>
</div>



#wrap {
    width: 600px;
    height: 800px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Now in my css code I need to set the px of height and width of the wrap div, right? Now this will work but the problem is. How do I get to optimize this then on another computer screen? I mean this wouldn't work on all the users right?

Anyway.. Let me repeat the question once again...
How do I my webpages to optimize to minimizing windows in the browsers and to work on all screens? I mean everything has to relate to pixels right? Now how the **** is that suppose to work If all the screen has different size's? I mean then you need to use the % to make it work. I don't want you guys to mainly sort of this exactly problem but give me some advice how to generally optimize a webpage in the best way.

Comment: If the question is not clear enough, I will repeat myself. As I said my english is not pefect so have some understanding of that. I also want to point out that I'm very new to stackoverflow, so the code lines might be a bit wired, hehe. Thank you!

Comment: Yes use % where appropriate to stretch elements. However more 'specific' elements such as header you may wish to keep fixed (header element fix by height for example).

Comment: @user2545642: it’s not just your English. “Let me repeat the question once again...” — how about you just write it once, clearly? Maybe in your native language first, then translate it to English as best you can. Your question is a bit rambling as it stands.

Comment: @user2545642: “whenever I minimize the window a bit, my div's shrinks togheter. That's not how I want it to appear.” How *do* you want it to appear?

Comment: I would strongly advise against using an ID `body`. This can be confusing at times, for yourself or co-workers.

Answer (score 2):

Ok here is what I usally do:

Whenever I want to create a website that doesn't fill 100% of the page I create a wrapper around ALL the content, like you did. You can either do this with fixed values or with % values. In case you want to use % values it's often smart to use `min-width` or `max-width` for your wrapper. This way you only need to define fixed values once and all the inner content can be defined by using %. This helps especially if you want to resize the whole content later on, if your realize that it might look better with a little bit more width.

Height values rarely use % values, only use % values for the height if you are using a fixed height for your container. If you want to create different layouts for different screen resolutions you can always have a look at the `@media` tag which allows you to create resolution specific css code. This however is only recommended for a small set of resolutions, let's say, 2 different resolutions for desktop computer and maybe 2 different resolutions for mobile phones (4 different css definitions).

I usually try to use `min-width` and `max-width` with % values, and if that isn't possible for example for popup windows or fixed elements like a sidebar I use px values. And if I for example want to support multiple columns for my content if the user has larger screens I make use of `@media`

I also don't get why you're using absolute positioning. If you just want to center content use `margin: 0 auto;` on your container. Btw in html5 you can also use the `<header>` tag if you want to specify a header. Using a div and giving it a class/id isn't wrong but I think you should know that there is some new stuff out there in the world of html5/css3

EIDT:
Your title is a little bit confusing, since your question is totally different. For website optimization I strongly recommend http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html or for advanced optimization you can use https://developers.google.com/closure/ and https://code.google.com/p/closure-stylesheets/

Answer (score 1):

Four your above code: 
you can use:

```
#wrap {
margin:0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: 800px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

instead of

```
#wrap {
    width: 600px;
    height: 800px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

And to make make your webpage look same when window is re-size or you have to learn abut **Responsive Web Development**. Start using media queries in you pages.
For responsive design use media queries: Here is good example of [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) . Also learn how to use it.

Comment: “Here is good example of media queries” — *Where* is good example of media queries?